# How to page multiple plots in R in separate jpeg files?

Tags: r, default, device, jpeg

I'd like to plot multiple plots in separate bitmap files using the file name pattern (for example, for JPEG) `file.%03d.jpg` in R. I tried using something like:

```
somevar <- 1
jpg(paste(sep='',filename,'.%03d.jpg'))
while(somevar <= n)
{
  plot(data[somevar])
  dev.new()
  somevar <- somevar + 1
}
dev.off()
```

but it creates one `.jpg` file and several `Rplotnnn.pdf` files. How can I change the default device to `jpg`, and use the custom file name pattern?

Comment: I would create a vector of names `my.names <- c("plot1.jpg", "plot2.jpg", "plot3.jpg")` and do `for (fn in my.names) ... jpeg(fn)...`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use JPEG rather than a vector format? I would suggest you use PNG or PDF format instead. The call is identical, just use `png` instead of `jpg` to set up the device.

Comment: Indeed. I use `png` now, besides, the problem was related to the somewhat esoteric `dev` mechanism in R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should work

```
somevar <- 1
while(somevar <= n) {
  jpg(sprintf("%s%03.jpg", filename, somevar))
  plot(data[somevar])
  dev.off()
  somevar <- somevar + 1
}
```

Plotting goes from device opening (here `jpeg(...)`) to `dev.off()`. You control the filename (where I corrected your use of `paste()` to `sprintf()`) and the loop.

Comment: Why the choice of sprintf over paste?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove the dev.new() from your code?  The jpg function/device should generate the multiple files following your pattern as long as you keep writing to the jpg device (the device.new call starts a new device each time, hence the pdf files).

Comment: Only one `jpg` file was created in that case.