# R Using lapply to save plots

Tags: r, graphics, time-series

I have a list of model objects called `allAR1`. For each model object, I need to use the `tsdiag` function to produce the diagnostics plot and then save that plot to a folder.

I am trying to use a combination of jpeg(), lapply and dev.off() to apply `tsdiag` to each model and then save the resulting plot as an image file. The problem is that this only seems to save the diagnostic plot for the first model in the `allAR1` list, whereas I would like to save the diagnostic plots for all models in `allAR1`.

Here is my code and a reproducible example:

```
library(tseries)

data(nino)

nino = list(nino3 = nino3, nino4 = nino3.4)

ar <- function(dat, idx, order, m) {

  paes = arima(dat, order = order)
  bic = paes$loglik + m*log(length(dat))
  res = residuals(paes)

  all = list(paes = paes, 
             bic = bic, 
             res = res)

  assign(idx, all)

  return(all)

}


allAR1 = mapply(ar, dat = nino, idx = names(nino), 
                MoreArgs = list(order = c(1,0,0), m = 1), 
                SIMPLIFY = F)

allpaes = lapply(allpaes, function(x) x$paes)
jpeg(sprintf("C:/Users/owner/Documents/%s.jpeg", names(nino)))
lapply(allAR1, tsdiag, gof.lag = 1000)
dev.off()
```

I have also tried `lapply(allAR1, function(x) {jpeg(sprintf("C:/Users/owner/Documents/%s.jpeg", names(nino))); tsdiag(x$paes, 1000); dev.off()})`. However, this gives me the same result as the code above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a code snippet to get you started:

```
library(tseries)
#from tsdiag help page
fit <- arima(lh, c(1,0,0))
#make an arbitrary list of model fits
models <- list(m1 = fit, m2 = fit)

lapply(1:length(models), function(x){
  jpeg(paste0(names(models)[x], ".jpeg"))
  tsdiag(models[[x]])
  dev.off()
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. However, I'm still not sure why `jpeg(paste0(names(models), ".jpeg"));
lapply(models, tsdiag, gof.lag = 1000);
dev.off()` only saves the diagnostic plots for m1 and not m2. What am I missing?

Comment: @user51462 - as far as I know, JPEG has no notion of multiple pages and there’s nothing in your code to iterate through different plots. There are related questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201515/how-to-page-multiple-plots-in-r-in-separate-jpeg-files